# Ansible fails to pull docker image from aws ecr (registry)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, docker-registry, ansible-2.x

ansible: 2.3, trying to pull image with docker_container step.

Did all the steps of [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper.git)
still when ansible in the docker_container step it fails on

```
 message: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Thing is that on the remote machine I'm able to pull the image manually.
I have only one user there (ec2-user of aws) - so it's seems like ansible thing. thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking about using the credential helper, but ended up using the AWS CLI instead.  Probably should switch to the helper, but in case anyone is interested, here's a short ansible snippet to install the CLI and authenticate to ECR through that with your instances IAM role. https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/25/ansible-install-aws-cli-and-log-in-to-amazon-ecr-docker-registry-via-ansible/

Answer (score 1):

So, you have configured amazon-ecr-credential-helper for the ec2-user on remote machine, and the images can be pulled manually. While, executing the playbook, I think that you are **executing the play as root or with become: yes**.

If you are executing the playbook with become: yes, then the image pull would fail because, the task is executed as root.